# How to work with serial pins when creating a custom gsource?

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I'm trying to write a subclass of GSource to work with serial port events. The way I found to do that is using the POSIX terminal interface, that work using file descriptors. For any reason, the Main Event Loop of GLib has a special way to deal with this variable.

As the [official documentation says](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFuncs), there is two GSource abstract functions that is used to prepare to dispatch, one to run before the pool of fds and one after. This shows that probably is important let GLib handle the file descriptors instead implement this in my own prepare function, but [there is no condition](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#GIOCondition) like "pin state changed" to work with serial port pins. About this I have some questions.

1. Why the choice from GLib team to make the library handle the file descriptor?
2. Can I get some issue if I just ignore it and implement this in my own prepare function?

Answer (score 0):

1. `GSource` needs to handle the file descriptor as it needs to be able to pass it to `poll()` for the low-level event polling.
2. Your question is unclear. Ignore what? Implement what?

I suspect you should be able to just use a `GUnixFDSource` created with [`g_unix_fd_source_new()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-UNIX-specific-utilities-and-integration.html#g-unix-fd-source-new) to watch for input on the terminal FD. In its callback (`g_source_set_callback()`) you should be able to read from the FD using the normal terminal I/O functions. The `GSource` is effectively just there to integrate the FD into a global event loop (the [`GMainContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html)).